# Datatable tabletool pdf Export shows some extra rows at last

Tags: html, datatable, datatables

When i used the datatable tabletool pdf export, there is an extra column at last with content of two rows.
Html part:

```
<table class="example tab" id="trip_tabless">
    <tfoot class="tabl tab-abs">
    <tr>
    <th style="display:none"></th>
    <th style="display:none"></th>
    <th style="display:none"></th>
    <th style="display:none"></th>
    <th style="display:none"></th>
    <th style="width:300px" id='plateno'></th>
    <th style="display:none"></th>
    <th style="width:300px" id='cancelled'></th>
    <th style="display:none"></th>
    <th style="display:none"> </th>
    </tr>
    </tfoot>
    <thead>
    <tr>
    <th style="display:none">Booking #</th>
    <th style="width:300px">Booking Date</th>
    <th style="display:none">Customer Details</th>
    <th style="display:none">Booking Type</th>
    <th style="display:none">Driver Id</th>
    <th style="display:none">Auto Plate #</th>
    <th style="display:none">Driver Response</th>
    <th style="display:none">Cancelled</th>
    <th style="display:none">Total Fare</th>
    <th style="display:none">Action</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <th>Booking #</th>
    <th>Booking Date</th>
    <th>Customer Details</th>
    <th>Booking Type</th>
    <th>Driver Id</th>
    <th>Auto Plate #</th>
    <th>Driver Response</th>
    <th>Cancelled</th>
    <th>Total Fare</th>
    <th>Action</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>        
    <tbody>
        <tr><td>5</td><td>Jun 10,2015</td> <td><span class="drive-name">Karthik</span><span class="drive-phone">11111111111</span></td><td>Fast Booking</td><td>auto plateno</td> <td>test test</td><td>Accepted</td><td>No</td> <td>25.12833404541</td>  <td> <a href="#"><button class="view-btn btn-sm"><span class="icon"></span></button></a></td></tr>
            <tr><td>4</td><td>Jun 10,2015</td> <td><span class="drive-name">Karthik</span><span class="drive-phone">11111111111</span></td><td>Fast Booking</td><td>auto plateno</td> <td>test test</td> <td>Accepted</td> <td>No</td> <td>27</td><td> <a href="#"><button class="view-btn btn-sm"><span class="icon"></span></button></a></td></tr>
            <tr><td>3</td><td>Jun 10,2015</td> <td><span class="drive-name">Karthik</span><span class="drive-phone">11111111111</span></td><td>Fast Booking</td><td>auto plateno</td> td>test test</td> <td>Accepted</td><td>No</td> <td>27</td> <td> <a href="#"><button class="view-btn btn-sm"><span class="icon"></span></button></a></td></tr>
            <tr><td>2</td><td>Jun 10,2015</td> <td><span class="drive-name">Karthik</span><span class="drive-phone">11111111111</span></td><td>Fast Booking</td><td>auto plateno</td> <td>test test</td><td>Accepted</td> <td>No</td> <td>27</td> <td> <a href="#"><button class="view-btn btn-sm"><span class="icon"></span></button></a></td></tr>
            <tr><td>1</td><td>Jun 12,2015</td> <td><span class="drive-name">Karthik</span><span class="drive-phone">11111111111</span></td><td>Manual Booking</td><td>auto plateno</td> <td>test test</td><td>Accepted</td> <td>No</td> <td>27</td><td> <a href="#"><button class="view-btn btn-sm"><span class="icon"></span></button></a></td></tr></tbody></table>
```

Please help me how to get the correct rows alone in the exported pdf file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is pretty straightforward.

You need to use `mColumns`, which defines which columns are included in the export that will be used in the PDF.

http://datatables.net/extensions/tabletools/button_options#mColumns

Comment: Sorry. This is not the solution for my question. I am not saying about the columns, I got some extra row of records.

Comment: I was going by your text, which said: "When i used the datatable tabletool pdf export, there is an extra column at last with content of two rows." How do you define an "extra row"? What's in this row and what makes it "extra"?

Comment: It has all the column values combined

Comment: Sorry...still not following. Can you duplicate your code here and I'll try to take a look: http://live.datatables.net/